# Determining Process

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have data as below

```
Schedule
+------------+----------------+
|   Date     | Lesson Teacher |
+------------+----------------+
| 2018-01-03 | Math           |
| 2018-01-03 | English        |
| 2018-01-03 | Sports         |
| 2018-01-03 | Biology        |
| 2018-01-03 | Math           |
| 2018-01-03 | English        |
| 2018-01-03 | Sports         |
| 2018-01-03 | Biology        |
| 2018-01-04 | Math           |
| 2018-01-04 | English        |
| 2018-01-04 | Sports         |
| 2018-01-04 | Biology        |
+------------+----------------+

Teacher
+-------------+------------+-----------+
|   Lesson    |  Teacher   |  Priority |
+-------------+------------+-----------+
| Math        | Alex       |         1 |
| Math        | Bob        |         2 |
| Math        | Steve      |         3 |
| English     | Alex       |         1 |
| English     | Bertha     |         2 |
| Sports      | Noah       |         1 |
| Sports      | Steve      |         2 |
| Biology     | Bertha     |         1 |
| Biology     | Bob        |         2 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

Every teacher only can teach 1 lesson in a date, so if the schedule already filled with first priority teacher the next will be fill with the second in the same date of lesson schedule. Does anyone can help?

thx

Comment: What is the question? And... can you also show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the windows functions

```
select sch.date, sch.lesson, t.teacher
from teacher t
join 
(
   select s.*,
        row_number() over (partition by date, lesson order by date) priority
   from schedule s
) sch on sch.lesson = t.lesson and t.priority = sch.priority
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6767223717b7b118b8685cfa876e31dc)

Comment: _The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY_